# Is there an easy way to automatically run a script whenever I (re)start a container?

Tags: docker

I have built a Docker image, copied a script into the image, and automatically execute it when I run the image, thanks to this Dockerfile command:

`ENTRYPOINT ["/path/to/script/my_script.sh"]`

(I had to give it chmod rights in a RUN command to actually make it run)

Now, I'm quite new to Docker, so I'm not sure if what I want to do is even good practice:

My basic idea is that I would rather not always have to create a new container whenever I want to run this script, but to instead find a way to re-execute this script whenever I (re)start the same container.

So, instead of having to type `docker run my_image`, accomplishing the same via `docker (re)start container_from_image`.

Is there an easy way to do this, and does it even make sense from a resource parsimony perspective?

Answer (score 1):

`docker run` is fairly cheap, and the typical Docker model is generally that you always start from a "clean slate" and set things up from there.  A Docker container doesn't have the same set of pre-start/post-start/... hooks that, for instance, a systemd job does; there is only the ENTRYPOINT/CMD mechanism.  The way you have things now is normal.

Also remember that you need to delete and recreate containers for a variety of routine changes, with the most important long-term being that you have to delete a container to change the underlying image (because the installed software or the base Linux distribution has a critical bug you need a fix for).  I feel like a workflow built around `docker build`/`run`/`stop`/`rm` is the "most Dockery" and fits well with the immutable-infrastructure pattern.  Repeated `docker stop`/`start` as a workflow feels like you're trying to keep *this* specific container alive, and in most cases that shouldn't matter.

From a technical point of view you can think of the container environment and its filesystem, and the main process inside the container.  `docker run` is actually `docker create` plus `docker start`.  I've never noticed the "create" half of this taking substantial time, but if you're doing something like starting a JVM or loading a large dataset on startup, the "start" half will be slow whether or not it's coupled with creating a new container.

Answer (score 1):

**For chmod issue** you can do something like this

```
COPY . /path/to/script/my_script.sh
RUN chmod 777 -R /path/to/script/my_script.sh
```

**For rerun script issue**

The `ENTRYPOINT` specifies a command that will always be executed when the container starts.

It can be either

```
docker run container_from_image
```

or

```
docker start container_from_image
```

So whenever your container start your `ENTRYPOINT` command will be executed.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile) for more detail